# Master code for Samsung laptop BIOS

Tags: laptop, bios

I set my Samsung password to empty but when saved and exit,I saw that is still has password.

I tried old password and new empty password but no difference.
it gives em this error when I try 3 password.

Here are the details:

```
System disabled!
006A9B910730C00C00
```

and sometimes:

```
System disabled!
1AA9CD4638C0186000
```

I'm looking for Master password generator based on this hash code,

here is the laptop info:

```
Serial no:  HYJD91BC900239M
Model Code: NP300E5X-T02AE
```

I used online apps to get the master code, but they work for twelve-digit hash codes.
http://dogber1.blogspot.ca/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html

Can anyone help me with a free solution?

Comment: Have you tried pulling out the cmos battery to reset the bios?

Comment: I cannot connect open it,because there is an stick on it for warranty.

Comment: you should go to service center then

Comment: Hi AliRezza, Your link works on my Samsung laptop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought online code from ebay and it works now.
the warranty service told me that bios IC should be replaced ,
replacing battery does not work on new samsung laptops.

Answer (score 7):

You should remove and put back the CMOS battery. It will reset the BIOS memory.

If you can't open laptop then you should visit service center or a professional.

Comment: it does not work in new samsung laptops

Comment: it will work but if removed for long time. Due to capacitors of high capacity the charge remains for long time.

Comment: I tested long time + pressed power + ... , No one didn't worked,I called warranty service they told me Bios IC should be replaced.

Comment: Modern systems store the password in non-viotile memory. Resetting the viotile memory by removing the battery no longer works for these.

Answer (score 0):

system disable massage
     type code -c125466300000000

this link...
             https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reset-remove-clear-or-reveal-cmos-bios-security-password/

genrate your master code

Comment: A well-written answer will include information FROM the linked sources, leaving the links just for verification, so that people do not have to follow the link to get the answer. As it is written, this is a poor-quality answer which is likely to be removed unless you edit it.